# Is the tensor product of left artinian algebras left artinian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

I know that if $A$ is artinian and $B$ is finite-dimensional, then $A\otimes B$ is artinian because $A\otimes B\cong A^n$ as $A$-modules. If we weaken the dimensionality assumption to $B$ being artinian, does $A\otimes B$ remain artinian? What if we make additional assumptions on $A$ and $B$, such as both being simple and $A$ being central? A particular case that interests me is the case of $A\otimes_KL$ for $L/K$ an arbitrary extension and $A$ a simple central artinian $K$-algebra, i.e. the base extension of $A$ to $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the tensor product of two field extensions may not be artinian.

For example (this is probably not the easiest way to see it) there is a [theorem of Sharp and Grothendieck](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/9/1/42/293400) that states that if $K/k$ and $L/k$ are field extensions, then the Krull dimension of $K\otimes_kL$ is the minimum of the transcendence degrees of $K$ and $L$ as extensions of $k$.

So, for example, $\mathbb{Q}(t)\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}(t)$ has Krull dimension $1$ and so can't be artinian.

Comment: Tough luck, thanks for the answer! I've got another question, if you don't mind: if $D$ is a division $K$-algebra (no assumptions on centrality or dimensionality) and $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, when can we say that $D\otimes_KL$ is simple? I'm guessing this rarely holds, since for example if $L/K$ is inseparable and $D$ is a field, then $D\otimes_KL$ has nilpotents and thus ideals (e.g. the nilradical).

Comment: @V.Ch. I don't know, sorry. But there are easy separable counterexamples: e.g., $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ is not simple.